# Having issues when trying to insert an ajax response which is an html block into an element on IE 8 using innerHTML

Tags: javascript

Hello Everyone just like my title states, I am having issues with IE8 and innerHTML. For whatever reason, when I make an ajax call which returns an html block and try to insert it into an element using innerHTML, the browser gives me an error "Unknown Error Code: 0".

The interesting part of this is that, if the message response does not have html element, innerHTML works. My code is like so:

```
setTimeout(function() {

 element.innerHTML = context.response.message;
}, 1000).bind(context)
```

WORKS:

```
context.response.message = 'String';
```

Does not WORK:

```
context.response.message = '<p>String</p>';
```

Comment: That's really weird.  Can you show us a demo?

Answer (score 0):

Ok ok, I figured it out... For what ever reason, IE8 and IE7 does not like:

```
Problem:
<p>Hi
   <p>Hi again</p>
</p>

Fix:
<div>Hi
   <p>Hi again</p>
</div>
```

Firefox seems to not care if you nest p tags, however, IE 8 and 7 poop on itself :(.

Thanks for your response.

Comment: Don't thnk you can nest <p>.. by definition the paragraph ends when a </p> or <p> is encountered.. Probably IE is breaknig because the HTML is badly formated.. If you remove the </p> it should work also.

Comment: A paragraph cannot contain block level elements, including <p> itself.
http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1